# Modifying MongoDB response object with previous next limit and offset

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose, hateoas

I am using express/Mongoose to fetch articles based on an app.get('/articles') type  call and respond with a list of articles.

```
articlesRoute.get(function(req, res) {

  Article.find(function(err, articles) {
if (err)
  res.send(err);

res.json(articles);
  });
});
```

I would like to modify the 'mongoose query result' and include the following in the responses object:

- link to itself
- previous article
- next article
- limit  (should default to 10, but changed to reflect user input if specified in req.query.limit)
- offset (defaults to 0, but changed to reflect user input if specified in req.query.offset)

I would like to include those as part of the JSON response object. This is to allow applications to be able to navigate easily from the call they make.

How best to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My apologies @JohnnyHK I have refined it, hopefully should be clearer now.

Comment: This still reads more like a work order than a question. It works much better if you get it as far as you can on your own and then ask a specific question about an aspect that's giving you trouble, if needed.